# How do I configure the XPM regions in the Tridion Reference Implementation?

Tags: dxa

How do I configure the XPM regions in the Tridion Reference Implementation?

I figured out you need to use the `@Markup.Region(Model)` helper, which reads the `system\mappings\regions.json` file. But I can't find what Component triggers the output of the `regions.json` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After examination of the code I found that the `regions.json` file is published as a binary when the `_System\Publish Settings` page is published.

The `Publish Mappings` TBB is used to create the regions configuration based on iterating over Component Template, where regions are automatically created based to the region name between [square-brackets] in the Component Template title. If the title does not specify a region name between square brackets, the region defaults to "Main".

After publishing of the `_System\Publish Settings` page, the settings in the web application should be refreshed by triggering the URL `/admin/refresh`. In my case however this does not work, I had to brute force delete the `BinaryData` folder for the changes to show up.

Comment: To add to this nice explanation, the region name is initially determined from the Component Template Metadata (if available), in most cases the Title with [square-brackets] postfix is used just to give a quick identifier of what the region is, but it also acts as a fallback in case there is no Component Template Metadata.

Answer (score 1):

In case of multilingual Web Site you need to republish `_System\Publish Settings` page from Master Web Site publication.

The way how it is implemented in PublishMappings .NET TBB from TRI v1.0.1 that all `mappings/includes` added to the package only if you are publishing from Master Web Site publication.

```
if (IsMasterWebPublication())
{
    filesCreated.AddRange(PublishJsonData(ReadMappingsData(), coreConfigComponent, "mapping", sg, true));
    filesCreated.Add(PublishJsonData(ReadPageTemplateIncludes(), coreConfigComponent, "includes", "includes", sg));
}
```

I have been hitting my head against wall for many hours to finally understand what is going on.

Comment: Indeed in TRI 1.0.x some configuration (like regions) is only published globally for a multi-publication site. In the yet to be released TRI 2.x all configuration is published for all publications

Comment: ...sorry about your head Stan

Comment: No worries! It worth to be documented ;)